# Visual Studio 2017 (ASPNetCore) Bower packages

Tags: bower

I noticed that when I use the "Manage Bower Package" by right clicking the project file, the installation will be successful, but the installed files won't go into the `wwwroot/lib` folder, therefore I won't be able to reference to it.

The only way I discovered so far is:

- Right click the project file-Add-New Item
- Choose ASP.NET Core-Web
- Find "Bower Configuration File"
- Add the package from there.

In this way, the installed files will appear in `wwwroot/lib`.

Does anyone experience the same?
Hope this sharing help someone and also clear my doubt.

Comment: I don't see manage bower packages. Was that removed?

Comment: I can't find "Manage bower packages" in my VS 2017 either. :(